# Aurelia.js how to add a new row in a table? without use jquery

Tags: javascript, aurelia

how can I add a new row in a table? using Aurelia.js without use jquery.

will be possible do this just with Aurelia.js ?

```js
export class App {
 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aurelia</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body aurelia-app>
   <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      elem 1
    </td>
    <td> elem 2</td>
    <td> elem 3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/bundles/aurelia.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/bundles/babel.js"></script>
    <script>
      require(['aurelia-bootstrapper']);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is, but you're an incredibly long way off having something working. Have you been through the tutorials offered on [aurelia.io](http://aurelia.io)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the thebluefox said, you're far way from having something working. You should read the docs and learn some basics.

Anyway, the answer you're looking for is:

```html
<tr repeat.for="item of items">
  <td>${item.property1}</td>
  <td>${item.property2}</td>
  <td>${item.property3}</td>
  <td>${item.property4}</td>
</tr>
```

Now, every time you push an object into `items`, a new line in the table will be created.

Hope this helps!